# Remove all duplicate object elements from array

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

This one's been giving me problems for a week, cross my fingers one of you can help me here...

This application was built on Laravel and the front scaffolded using Vue.

Thing is I have an array of objects that is supposed to be sent to the backend in order for it to be stored in a database. Thing is this is an editor and the idea is not reload the page every time something is changed, so here comes my problem...

The way of getting the information is through window.postMessage(), so it seems the information lingers on even after saving, since the page behavior is for it to not reload, I have tried emptying the array after firing the save function. Now it works the first time because the array is empty so there's nothing to compare it to, it also works the second time, but from the third time on, it duplicates some of the objects inside and stores them in DB.

Here's my code:

```
saveNewSettings() {
   //THIS IS THE ARRAY I NEED TO EMPTY (ALREADY DECLARED IN THE DATA OBJECT)
   /* this.newItems = [
                        { id="123", name="a", otherProps="someProps" },
                        { id="456", name="ab, otherProps="someProps" },
                        { id="789", name="c", otherProps="someProps" },
                      ]
   */
   //THIS IS THE AN EMPTY ARRAY I'M USING TO COMPARE LATER ON... (ALREADY DECLARED IN THE DATA OBJECT)
   // this.newlyCreatedItems = [];

   if ( !this.newlyCreatedItems.length ) {
      this.newlyCreatedItems = this.newItems;
   } else {
      for ( let i = 0; i < this.newItems.length; i++ ) {
          for ( let j = 0; j < this.newlyCreatedItems.length; j++ ) {
              if ( this.newItems[i].id == this.newlyCreatedItems[j].id ) {
                 this.newItems.splice( i, 1 );
              }
          }
      }
   }

   //THIS IS THE SERVICE I USE TO SEND THE INFO TO THE BACK END
   //THIS ONE HAS BEEN IMPORTED FROM AN SERVICE FILE
   settingsService.save( this.newItems )
   .then(response => {
        //WHAT TO DO AFTER THE RESPONSE GOES HERE
   });
}
```

So here's the thing, firing the function for the first time, since it's the first, doesn't duplicate anything in the database... For the second time, it works well and it only saves the new item, from the third time on, it starts duplicating.

If you need me to elaborate more, just let me know, I thank you all in advance...

Comment: Have you tried the temporary Array method? Basically loop through your existing array (in this case `this.newItems`), then you check if the temporary array contains the data or not. If it does not contains, push it to the array, otherwise don't do anything. Then you use that temp. array the items to be pushed

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty using jQuery:

```
var names = ["Mike","Matt","Nancy","Adam","Jenny","Nancy","Carl"];
var uniqueNames = [];
$.each(names, function(i, el){
    if($.inArray(el, uniqueNames) === -1) uniqueNames.push(el);
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I have already tried this one. Thing is this gives me an array without duplicates, but it doesn't remove all the matching objects, it leaves one. The idea is, I save the item for the first time, then, I need to remove the item that had been saved, and keep only the new items in the array. That's whay I'm trying to do... Thanks for the quick reply, pal. I honestly appreciate it.

Comment: @MichaelHaydn mention not. I will find a better way for this condition try this 

`const arr = [{id: 1, name: 'one'}, {id: 2, name: 'two'}, {id: 1, name: 'one'}]

const ids = arr.map(o => o.id)
const filtered = arr.filter(({id}, index) => !ids.includes(id, index + 1))

console.log(filtered)`

Answer (score 0):

You tagged `vue.js` but this problem statement is more like from `JavaScript` side. Basically, You are doing shallow copy of the `newItems` array into the `newlyCreatedItems` array which causing the updation issue as both are referencing to the same pointer address.

You can resolve this issue by deep copying with the help of [`structuredClone()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
let newItems = [
  { id: "123", name: "a", otherProps: "someProps" },
  { id: "456", name: "ab", otherProps: "someProps" },
  { id: "789", name: "c", otherProps: "someProps" }
];

let newlyCreatedItems = [];

function saveNewSettings() {
  if (!newlyCreatedItems.length ) {
    newlyCreatedItems = structuredClone(newItems);
  } else {
    for ( let i = 0; i < newItems.length; i++ ) {
      for ( let j = 0; j < newlyCreatedItems.length; j++ ) {
        if ( newItems[i].id == newlyCreatedItems[j].id ) {
          newItems.splice( i, 1 );
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

saveNewSettings();

console.log(newlyCreatedItems);
console.log(newItems);

console.log('-------');

saveNewSettings();

console.log(newlyCreatedItems);
console.log(newItems);
```